# Compression using Ascii, trying to figure out how many bits to store the following efficiently

Tags: string, binary, compression, ascii, bit

I am trying to learn the basics of compression using only ASCII.

If I am sending an email of strings of lower-case letters. If the file has `n`
characters each stored as an 8-bit extended ASCII code, then we need 8n bits.
But according to **Guiding principle of compression:** we discard the unimportant information.
So using that we don't need all ASCII codes to code strings of lowercase letters: they use only 26 characters. We can make our own code with only 5-bit codewords (25 = 32 > 26), code the file using this coding scheme and then decode the email once received.

```
The size has decreased by 8n - 5n = 3n, i.e. a 37.5% reduction.
```

But what IF the email was formed with lower-case letters (26), upper-case letters, and extra `m` characters and they have to be stored efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

If you have n symbols of equal probability, then it is possible to code each symbol using log2(n) bits.  This is true even if log2(n) is fractional, using arithmetic or range coding.  If you limit it to Huffman (fixed number of bits per symbol) coding, you can get close to log2(n), with still a fractional number of bits per symbol on average.

For example, you can encode ten symbols (e.g. decimal digits) in very close to 3.322 bits per symbol with arithmetic coding.  With Huffman coding, you can code six of the symbols with three bits and four of the symbols with four bits, for an average of 3.4 bits per symbol.

The use of shift-up and shift-down operations can be beneficial since in English text you expect to have strings of lower case characters with occasional upper case characters.  Now you are getting into both higher order models and unequal frequency distributions.

Comment: So suppose what is the maximum valued for m to be able to store F using a 6-bit code?????

Comment: you didnt understand the question.

Comment: Yes, that's what "Huh?" means.  What is "F"?

Comment: upper case "F" is what i mean

Comment: Then the answer is "F" takes one of the 64 codes, leaving m = 63.

Comment: what would the algorithm be in terms on n and m?

Comment: ASCII is a seven-bit code, so any symbol represented in ASCII, including "F", requires 7 bits.  "what would the algorithm be in terms on n and m?" makes no sense.  You need to edit your original question to be understandable, as opposed to having a conversation in these comments.